# HTMLElement definition in typescript.lib/lib.dom.d.ts was overridden by @types/react/global.d.ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[image]

The compiler find the definition of `HTMLElement`, but the definition from `react/global.d.ts` is taken instead of `typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts`.

Here's the compiler error:

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.  TS2339
```

Here are the differences:

#### In react/global.d.ts

```js
interface Element { }

interface HTMLElement extends Element { }
```

#### In typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts

```js
interface HTMLElement extends Element, GlobalEventHandlers, DocumentAndElementEventHandlers, ElementContentEditable, HTMLOrSVGElement, ElementCSSInlineStyle {
    accessKey: string;
    readonly accessKeyLabel: string;
    autocapitalize: string;
    dir: string;
    draggable: boolean;
    hidden: boolean;
    innerText: string;
    lang: string;
    readonly offsetHeight: number;
    readonly offsetLeft: number;
    readonly offsetParent: Element | null;
    readonly offsetTop: number;
    readonly offsetWidth: number;
    spellcheck: boolean;
    title: string;
    translate: boolean;
    click(): void;
    addEventListener<K extends keyof HTMLElementEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: HTMLElement, ev: HTMLElementEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;
    addEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;
    removeEventListener<K extends keyof HTMLElementEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: HTMLElement, ev: HTMLElementEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions): void;
    removeEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions): void;
}
```

So my question is: how to make the compiler choose `typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts` before the one from React? Any help would be greatly appreciated！

Edit: here's the `tsconfig.json`, correctly referencing the TS lib:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "incremental": true, // Enable incremental compilation by reading/writing information from prior compilations to a file on disk
    "sourceMap": true, // Generate corrresponding .map file
    "declaration": true, // Generate corresponding .d.ts file
    "noUnusedLocals": true, // Report errors on unused locals
    "noUnusedParameters": true, // Report errors on unused parameters
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue? If not, how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

update*

`e.target` is an HTMLElement, however it is NOT guaranteed to have the `value` property.

Try to cast event.target to the HTML element to ensure it is HTMLInputElement

```
(<HTMLInputElement>e.target).value
```

ref: https://angular.io/guide/user-input#!#type-the--*event*

---

old answer*

Try to use a type-assertion: `current as HTMLElement`

I can see the `element` is HTMLElement, however, you should check `current`.
I cannot see the initialization of `current` well because it is hidden by error message window.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help. I've changed the example for a simpler one, so the error is more obvious.

Comment: The Problem looks a bit different @_@

Answer (score 1):

`react/global.d.ts` exists as a placeholder for the sole purpose of allowing the compilation of React without depending on Typescript's DOM libary.
If this was not done, various parts of React would fail to compile unless `--lib DOM` (or the equivalent in `tsconfig.json`) is specified because of missing interface declarations.

The *real* DOM interfaces are declared in the DOM libary included in Typescript (i.e. `typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts`).

Both of them can coexist because Typescript merges `interface`s with equal names as long as they don't contain conflicting declarations.

---

**However, none of that is the cause of this problem.**
If we take a look at the declaration of `React.FormEvent` and its sibling `React.ChangeEvent` for comparison, we'll notice that `target` is not specified in the former. If we dig deeper into the inherited interfaces, we'll eventually find that `target` is of type `EventTarget`.

```ts
interface FormEvent<T = Element> extends SyntheticEvent<T> {
}

interface ChangeEvent<T = Element> extends SyntheticEvent<T> {
    // Note that target is also a T (e.g. HTMLInputElement) here
    target: EventTarget & T;
}
// ...
interface SyntheticEvent<T = Element, E = Event>
  extends BaseSyntheticEvent<E, EventTarget & T, EventTarget> {}
// ...
interface BaseSyntheticEvent<E = object, C = any, T = any> {
    // ...
    target: T; // T is EventTarget at this point
    // ...
}
```

A `React.FormEvent` doesn't have any particular element type as `target`, only a generic `EventTarget`.
This particular type of event can be captured at some parent element (e.g. a `<form>`) after propagating up from child elements (e.g. an `<input>`).
At the point of capture, the type of the originating element (`target`) is unknown during compilation and can thus not be declared exactly.

If the event is captured directly on a particular element of type `T` (e.g. an `<input>` or `HTMLInputElement`), it is actually of type `React.ChangeEvent<T>`. For example:

```tsx
<input ... onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    // It is known that target is an <input> element
    console.log(e.target.value);
}} />
```

If you want to capture this event at a parent element, you will have to determine the correct type of `target` manually (based on your own knowledge beyond what the compiler can infer) and cast it appropriately:

```tsx
<form ... onChange={(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    // I swear that the target is really an <input> element
    const target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
    console.log(target.value);
}}>
    <input ... />
</form>
```